# i am unable to login and can not validate my user

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","company");

if(mysqli_connect_error())
{
    echo "error in connecting to  database";
}

$email=$_POST[semail];
$password= md5($_POST[spassword]);


$query = "select email,password from register where email= '$email'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row["email"]==$email && $row["password"]==$password)
    echo "welcome";
else
    echo "Please try again";
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

this is my code please give me answer. i am unable to login by this code. and cant get it.
i am trying to do login form this code

Comment: are you getting error "Please try again" or what??

Comment: Some places its mysqsli & some its mysql. Also try debugging yourself where you will get a better idea.

Comment: try to login with this email: `' or true`. Please take a look here before write anything with mysql http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: try to echo your query and run it mysql.

Comment: Access through a constant: `$_POST[spassword]` acces to a string index: `$_POST['spassword']` notice the difference? Security issues also detected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple reason:

Mysqli:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","company");
```

and later old mysql:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Not mentioning the other problems in your code

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

you have to replace above code to my code

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
/* associative and numeric array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

$email=$_POST['semail'];
$password= md5($_POST['spassword']);
place in single or double quotes

Answer (score 0):

use `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_fetch_array`

and try..It worked at my end.